# Excel- counter for every hour

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I have some dates with time in my excel sheet, i was just wondering if there was a day to have a counter for each time it occurred in that hour. For example,

```
01-Jan-2015 05.04.18

01-Jan-2015 05.55.24

01-Jan-2015 06.01.45

02-Jan-2015 09.11.32
```

So there is 2 occurrences in the 05 hour of 1st Jan, 1 occurrence in 06 hour etc.

I would count it manually but there are over 10,000 lines.

Any idea how I could use a formula to set a counter, would I use COUNTIF, or concatenate it first?

I’m sorry if this sounds a little bit stupid, I am just a beginner.

Thanks for your help

Comment: look into COUNTIFS() with a S.  It will allow multiple criteria, not concatenation needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the date occurrences in Sheet1, column A. You could have a list of hours in column A of a second sheet (01-Jan-2015 05.00, 01-Jan-2015 06.00, 01-Jan-2015 07.00 etc.). In column B in that sheet you place a `COUNTIFS` formula which counts all date occurrences between the date and hour in column A and column A + 1 hour:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,">=" & A1,Sheet1!A:A,"<" & A1+(1/24))
```

See [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) for reference.